# Redis Id non readable

Tags: linux, redis, fedora

```
07c37dfeb235213a872192d90877d0cd55635b91 127.0.0.1:30004 slave e7d1eecce10fd6bb5eb35b9f99a514335d9ba9ca 0 1426238317239 4 connected
67ed2db8d677e59ec4a4cefb06858cf2a1a89fa1 127.0.0.1:30002 master - 0 1426238316232 2 connected 5461-10922
292f8b365bb7edb5e285caf0b7e6ddc7265d2f4f 127.0.0.1:30003 master - 0 1426238318243 3 connected 10923-16383
6ec23923021cf3ffec47632106199cb7f496ce01 127.0.0.1:30005 slave 67ed2db8d677e59ec4a4cefb06858cf2a1a89fa1 0 1426238316232 5 connected
824fe116063bc5fcf9f4ffd895bc17aee7731ac3 127.0.0.1:30006 slave 292f8b365bb7edb5e285caf0b7e6ddc7265d2f4f 0 1426238317741 6 connected
e7d1eecce10fd6bb5eb35b9f99a514335d9ba9ca 127.0.0.1:30001 myself,master - 0 0 1 connected 0-5460
```

Above is output of "CLUSTER NODES". 
id: The node ID, a 40 characters random string generated when a node is created and never changed again :  This is non readable, can i change it to more user friendly text like "Master1" or "SLave1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#cluster-nodes-attributes:

> Every node has a unique name in the cluster. The node name is the hex representation of a 160 bit random number, obtained the first time a node is started (usually using /dev/urandom). The node will save its ID in the node configuration file, and will use the same ID forever, or at least as long as the node configuration file is not deleted by the system administrator, or a hard reset is requested via the CLUSTER RESET command.

Which begs the question - have you tried editing the nodes' configuration files?

Comment: i have edited redis.conf.... so do you mean i cant overwirite name of node ?